# Apple iPad USB stick showing "External: open dir error, path = / "

Tags: ipad, usb, external-disk

Greetings dear community.

I bought a 128 USB stick for my Gilrfriend's Mac which works solely with an app called LUV-Share.

The USB was brand new and was supposed to store HD movies, which are above 4GB. This wasn't possible because the format of the stick was FAT32 so we formatted the stick to Mac OS Extended (Groß/Kleinschreibung/journaled), in order to be able to store bigger files. Now we have the movies in the stick but when opening the app and clicking the icon "External Storage" we get the following error:

"External: open dir error. path = /"

And this is where I find myself lost. Perhaps you could guide me to a solution for this matter.

Thank you in advance for your help and have a good day.

Sincerely,
Irendur

Comment: Which version of iOS do you have on the iPad?

Comment: it is iPadOS 13.4.1

Comment: If you open the Files app, can you then browse the contents of the USB drive?

Comment: on my Mac I can see and open the files of the movies stored in the USB but I can't open or even see the files on my iPad when I stick it to it.

Comment: So you have tried the Files app? - Which type of partition table do you have? (MBR or GPT?) - Is it formatted as HFS+ (not encrypted) ?

Comment: the "Generic SD/MMC Media" partition table is MBR and it is formatted APFS (not encrypted)

Comment: Hmm - in your question you wrote that it was formatted as HFS+ (MacOS Extended). Now you say it is APFS. Can you double-triple check?

Comment: oh yes, sorry.
the USB is formatted MacOS Extended

Comment: How did you check that it is MacOS Extended? Is it not journaled?

Comment: I double checked it in "disk utility"

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? - Sounds odd you haven't formatted it as journaled?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, just back up any files you have on there, then reformat to exFat and then put your data back in, The limitation of exFat filing system, am I right. Lol